# Can't store output of php $.get() function to javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know there are a lot of questions regarding this topic, but I've searched and searched and I'm stuck, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to store the HTTP output of a php file into my javascript variable, but it doesn't work like intended.

So far I have this on the client side:

```
var modDate;

function getModDate() {
    $.get('checkModDate.php?filename=plot.svg', function (data) {
        modDate = data;
    });
    return modDate;
}

$(document).ready(function () { // Execute when page has loaded
    alert(getModDate());
});
```

And on the server side:

```
<?php
$filename = $_GET["filename"];

if (file_exists($filename)) {
  echo filemtime($filename);
}
?>
```

The output of the alert is just 'undefined'.

However, if I just put the alert into the getModDate() function like this:

```
function getModDate(){
  $.get('checkModDate.php?filename=plot.svg', function(data) {
       modDate = data;
       alert(modDate);
   });
}
```

I get the correct output. 
What am I missing!? I have declared modDate as a global variable, so I can't figure out what's causing this behaviour.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One word - async.

In first case, the return is triggered before the callback of `$.get` is executed.

Would suggest reading up on event loop and basic async handling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
It makes sense that async would cause the behaviour.

I found a way to handle the asynchronous behaviour by reading this answer about synchronous/asynchronous JS.
Thanks!